# clone git repo from command line securly

Tags: git, shell, github, debian

git clone https://username:password@github.com/xyz-abc/RUBIKS-CUBE-SOLVER.git

trying to write  shell script to clone git repository
but have to pass my *username* and *password* direct

so is there any alternative or secure or encrypted way where in i can hide my *username* and *password* from other and clone the repository.

i am on *Debian 6*.

Comment: why do you need to provide username/password at all, when cloning a github-repository via `https://`? here i'm allowed to clone without authentication (only when i push to the repository, i have to authenticate). or is this a *private* repository?

Comment: yes its a private repo @umläute

Comment: i am trying to write a shell script with following command in it  https://username:password@github.com/xyz-abc/RUBIKS-CUBE-SOLVER.git

Comment: the main thing this shell script is the first thing to happen after the operating system installation

Answer (score 1):

use the ssh-access to github:

```
 git clone git+ssh://git@github.com/xyz-abc/RUBIKS-CUBE-SOLVER.git
```

and use certificates for authentification

Comment: how can i achieve it in within a shell script....
actually i want to write a shell script which well clone all repo on its execution but don't want to expose my password for the one who opens my shell script

Comment: simply put it in the shell-script... i don't fully understand your question (or rather: problem)

Comment: i am trying to write a shell script with following command in it  https://username:password@github.com/xyz-abc/RUBIKS-CUBE-SOLVER.git and when every of the client m\c on lan runs it daily they will get this fresh clone copy.... but if client on lan they open the shell script and have a look they can see the git-hub password in url and i don't want that to happen

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys ....i tried it but the main problem with my shell script is it is startup shell shell script for setting up work environment for new user...can i do something like other can run my shell script and they will get the repo but will not get my password..... the main thing this shell script is the first thing to happen after the operating system installation

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `git` > `1.8.3` you can use an `gpg` encrypted `.netrc` to store your password. You can find a guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309).

If you're using `git` with a version < `1.8.3` you can store the passwords in a file but only in plain text. If you're using linux you can write a `.netrc` file and make it readable only by the user.

Your `.netrc` should contain:

```
machine myRemoteServer
login myUserName
password s3cret
```

Make it readable only by the user:

```
 chmod 600 .netrc
```

Comment: as i am writing the shell script i have to give the password to it and the user can easily see the password..